# Why isn't my git hook firing?

Tags: githooks

I'm trying to write a git hook that fires on `git pull`, `git merge`, and `git checkout`, when my `.emacs` file changes. For some reason, the hook never seems to fire.

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/hooks/post-merge-checkout

Answer (score 0):

osse on #git / #bash helped me identify the issue: I was using the wrong git command to search for file changes. The new one works:

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/594e24d28e599e57b401d3c163d72498b8a3c1f0/hooks/post-merge-checkout